# Google script 'GetValue' doesn't read values filled with 'Query' in spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, getvalue

Some sheets in my spreadsheet have data filled by the Query formula.

In a sheet I have data filled by a Query of another sheet filled by a Query itself.

This double Query makes that I can't read data usign GetValues() from a script.

When I try the simplest reading using:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Timeline');
var data = sheet.getRange('A15').getValue();
Logger.log(data);
```

the outcome is empty. In the cell A15 I have a query formula calling a sheet where data are filled by a Query, in turn.

Google script can't read values from a query of a query, I reckon.

Do you have any idea please?

Thanks.

Comment: Does `A15` itself contain a value? I can't recreate this behaviour you mention.

Comment: `A15` contains a query formula. Exactly the following:

`=IFERROR(QUERY(Dates!C3:J, "Select D,I,J,G  where D!='' and toDate(I)> Date '31-12-2000' order by I,C"))`

The fact is that the range `Dates!C3:J` is populated itself by a Query. I got the this is the error, but there is a solution to that?
Thanks Robin.

Comment: Did you check the value that is in A15? is it blank? Possibly due to the sorting.

Comment: No, I excluded blanks from the selection. I've checked and the error is due to the following statement in the query:

`toDate(I)> Date '31-12-2000'` that I need because I want to exclude some row that in column `I` has by default '31-12-1899'
How can I clean data in another way?

Answer (score 0):

@Robin
The problem was the *where clause* `toDate(I)> Date '31-12-2000'`.

I've replaced it with `YEAR(I)>2000` and the script reads all cells now.

The reason I use the clause is because in my query I need to exclude rows with empty dates. Although they appear empty it seems they have some hidden value that I reckon is `31-12-1899`. 
This is probably because the cell is formatted as Date. I'll investigate in it and this should also be another question that is not related with the current one.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because dates are in timestamp. and your query probably consider your empty value as a 0, that correspond in timestamp, to the first time ( which is 1/1/1900 at 00h00, then, each increment represent a second.

You should try a blank detection with soething like:

```
var A= getCell(x,Y).getValue()
if (A=""){ 
....
}
```